how to create a dynamic breadcrumbs in laravel php?
I am working on a project and I needed to use breadcrumbs Package laravel-breadcrumbs

Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
});

The code Above is My Main/home route
Route::get('/collections/{id}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show'])->name('collections');
And this is My Collections route code Above
I want to create a breadcrumbs logic looks like this : home/Collections/1 and instead of an ID I want the name of the collection,
home/Collections/collectionName.
**Here is My Controller code: **
public function show(Sous_categorie $sous_categorie, $id)
{

    //dd($id);
    $count = DB::table('produits')->select('produits.sous_categorie_id')->where('produits.sous_categorie_id', '=', $id)->get();
    //return response()->json($count);
    $s_marque = DB::table('produits')
        ->select('marque')
        ->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
        ->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$id])->get();
    //dd($s_marque);
    $f_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')->where('categorie_id', '=', $id)->get();
    $s_produits = DB::table('produits')
        ->select('produits.*', 'sous_categories.categorie_id as laravel_through_key')
        ->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
        ->where('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$id])
        ->paginate(8)->withQueryString();
    //dd($f_categorie);
    $product = Produit::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(12)->withQueryString();
    $prods = Produit::with('souscategories')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8)->withQueryString();
    $categories = Categorie::all();
    $sous_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')->where('categorie_id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%')->get();
    //$s_produits = DB::table('produits')->select('*')->where('sous_categorie_id','like','%'.$id.'%')->get();
    //return response()->json($s_produits);

    return view('collections.components', compact('sous_categorie', 'id', 'f_categorie', 'categories', 'prods', 'product', 's_produits', 's_marque', 'count'));
}

Well I tried creating the breadcrumbs on the breadcrumbs.php file I created based on the documentation of the Package in the code below:
<?php // routes/breadcrumbs.php

// Note: Laravel will automatically resolve `Breadcrumbs::` without
// this import. This is nice for IDE syntax and refactoring.
use Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Breadcrumbs;

// This import is also not required, and you could replace `BreadcrumbTrail $trail`
//  with `$trail`. This is nice for IDE type checking and completion.
use Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Generator as BreadcrumbTrail;

// Home
Breadcrumbs::for('home', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) {
    $trail->push('Home', route('/dashboard'));
});

// Home > Blog
Breadcrumbs::for('collections', function ($trail) {
    $trail->push('Collections', route('collections'));
});

And render it on the balde view like this: {!! Breadcrumbs::render() !!}, it throws back an error:
`Missing required parameter for [Route: collections] [URI: collections/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].
Please ! Help

Please send your SousCategorieController.php

You can use slug, name or whatever you want instead of id.
Check your DB if your collection table has for example name row you can set it in your route.
Then you should change your route and controller. We assume that you have collection name in your DB.
Controller should be something like this:
    public function show(Sous_categorie $sous_categorie, $parameter)
{    
$count = DB::table('produits')
->select([
'produits.sous_categorie_id AS id',
'produits.sous_categorie_name AS name'
])
->where('produits.sous_categorie_id', $parameter)
->orWhere('produits.sous_categorie_name', $parameter)
->get();

$s_marque = DB::table('produits')
->select('marque')
->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$parameter])
 ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
     $query->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_name', [$parameter]);           
    })
->get();

$f_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')->where('categorie_id', $parameter)->orWhere('categorie_name', $parameter)->get();
$s_produits = DB::table('produits')
->select([
'produits.*', 
'sous_categories.categorie_id AS laravel_through_key',
'sous_categories.categorie_name AS laravel_through_key_name'
])
->join('sous_categories', 'sous_categories.id', '=', 'produits.sous_categorie_id')
->where('sous_categories.categorie_id', [$parameter])
->orWhere(function($query)
    {
     $query->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_name', [$parameter]);           
    })
->paginate(8)->withQueryString();

$product = Produit::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(12)->withQueryString();
$prods = Produit::with('souscategories')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8)->withQueryString();
$categories = Categorie::all();
$sous_categorie = DB::table('sous_categories')->select('*')
->where('categorie_id', 'like', '%' . $parameter . '%')
->orWhere('categorie_name', 'like', '%' . $parameter . '%')
->get();

return view('collections.components', compact('sous_categorie', 'id', 'name', 'f_categorie', 'categories', 'prods', 'product', 's_produits', 's_marque', 'count'));
} 
 

And route should be
Route::get('/collections/{parameter}', [SousCategorieController::class, 'show'])->name('collections');


but my logic is build on thet ID filtering and pagination and so on .. what should I do ?

Pagination will work fine

what about other querys ? should I just filter on the name .

you can use name ad id at the same time

please tell me how to do that with my example ?

I changed it. Please edit my code related to your real rows name and table as I don't have info about your app.

Am sorry I couldn't apply your answer to my code
